# Facebook application to display friend list in jsp

Tags: jsp, facebook

How to create a facebook application to display friend list in jsp page without using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preprocess a request, you need to create a `Servlet` and implement the `doGet()` method. Inside this method you can freely write/invoke Java code as you want without cluttering the JSP file with scriptlets. Make use of `java.net.URL` and/or `java.net.URLConnection` inside the `doGet()` method to access the Facebook API by HTTP requests and obtain data as HTTP response. Finally process this data in flavor of `List<Friend>` and forward the request to JSP page for display.

Kickoff example:

```
public class FacebookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://url/to/some/facebook/API/to/get/list/of/friends"); // Read Facebook API doc for the correct URL.
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        List<Friend> friends = extractFriends(input); // Do your job here.
        request.setAttribute("friends", friends); // It's then available as ${friends} in JSP.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/friends.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of for example `/friends` so that you can invoke it by `http://example.com/contextname/friends`.

Then, in your `/WEB-INF/friends.jsp` (the JSP is placed in `/WEB-INF` to prevent from direct access without using the servlet), make use of [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) `c:forEach` tag to iterate over the `List<Friend>` and print a HTML table row (`<tr>`) on every iteration:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${friends}" var="friend">
        <tr>
            <td>${friend.name}</td>
            <td>${friend.age}</td>
            <td>${friend.email}</td>
            <td>etc..</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: shall u provide sample example for url?

Comment: Read Facebook API doc for the correct URL. http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API